# Invalid credentials postman

Tags: sql, migration, knex.js

I hard coded the users in my seed file
I can view the the users in the database
But when i try to test the details in the database i get an error "invalid credentials"
I don't know why it says that when the user is already in the database

This is the seeds file

```
const noPassword = "$2a$12$ZQwXBTq7UMgmugpy5zz9SOdG4JvEa3Bj5MofQl9fIMFb1wTSGU9.C"; exports.seed = function (knex) { // Deletes ALL existing entries return knex("users") .truncate() .then(function () { // Inserts seed entries return knex("users").insert([ { email: "danielAsuquo15@gmail.com", first_name: "Daniel", last_name: "Asuquo", password:noPassword, }, { email: "josiahdamiwilliams@gmail.com", first_name: "josiah", last_name: "williams", password:noPassword, }, ]); }); };
```

---